# How to automatically disconnect API Gateway websocket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I'm making a chat app, and I want the duration of the AWS API Gateway websocket connection to be 5 minutes. How do I set the websocket to automatically disconnect at the specified time?
I couldn't find a native solution on the Websockets console.
Step functions, EventBridge seem insanely complicated for this simple task.
What are some quick solutions?